# react: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm studying reactjs from the document. When I transmit the data passed by state. eg. `getInitialState()` I get an error:

> Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

I try to change `getInitialState()` to `this.state = { data : []}`. However this is not right way. How can I fix it?

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello React</title>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/showdown/0.3.1/showdown.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/t39.3284-6/11057105_1610731242494235_1148661094_n.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
</head>

    <body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script type="text/jsx">

        //Comment text
        let converter = new Showdown.converter();
        let Comment = React.createClass({
            render(){
                let rawMarkup = converter.makeHtml(this.props.children.toString())
                return (
                        <div className="comment">
                            <h2 className="commentAuthor">
                                { this.props.author }
                            </h2>
                            <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: rawMarkup}}/>
                        </div>
                );
            }
        });

        //Comment list
        let CommentList = React.createClass({
            render(){
                let commentNodes = this.props.data.map((comment, index) => {
                    return (
                            <Comment author={comment.author} key={index}>
                                { comment.text }
                            </Comment>
                    )
                });
                return (
                        <div className="commentList">
                            { commentNodes }
                        </div>
                );
            }
        });


        //Comment form
        let CommentForm = React.createClass({
            render(){
                return (
                        <div className="commentForm">
                            CommentForm !!
                        </div>
                );
            }
        });

        //Comment component
        let CommentBox = React.createClass({
            getInitialState(){
                return {
                    data: [
                        {author: "Pete Hunt", text: "This is one comment"},
                        {author: "Jordan Walke", text: "This is *another* comment"}
                    ]
                }
            },
            render(){
                return (
                        <div className="commentBox">
                            <h1>Comments</h1>
                            <CommentList data={ this.state.data }/>
                            <CommentForm />
                        </div>
                );
            }
        });

        
        React.render(
                <CommentBox data={this.state.data}/>,   //<----[ERROR IS　HERE Uncaught TypeError]
                document.getElementById('content')
        );
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The states are handled independently by the components. You are trying to access the state *outside* of a React component. You are passing { this.state.data } as a prop when you don't need the prop in the first place. You should be able to remove the data prop entirely and your code will work just fine.

`<CommentBox /> // get rid of data prop`

Comment: it's solve my problem。Your explanation is very detailed.thank you very much

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!